# Quick launch as flyout menu without using SharePoint Designer

Tags: web-part, css, script

I'm responsible for a subsite in my companies intranet and I wanted to transform the static Quick Launch menu of SharePoint into a Flyout Menu. On the web and in this forum I found several solutions by using SharePoint Designer. But actually I neither have SharePoint Designer nor access to the Top-Level-Site of the SharePoint. I only have Site Owner rights on the site I am responsible for.

Is it probably possible by putting a specific code into the Script Editor WebPart? I'm using SharePoint 2013

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Oh sry, excuse me: SharePoint 2013

Comment: Have you found any solution without SharePoint designer?

Comment: I've not any access to SharePoint Designer in my company. It is unfortunately not allowed to use it here

Comment: So it is not possible.. My answer already explains the same... I am on the right track to give you a solution.. :)

Comment: can you mark the answer as it is the only solution we do have for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry mate but it **might not be possible**.

You must have to change the controls settings using SharePoint designer.

As you have mentioned, You do not have access to SharePoint Designer so i think it **might be not possible** using any script. Because you must have to change `StaticDisplayLevels` and `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevel` within `V4QuickLaunchMenu` to make it `flyout`.

If you want to change the `Global Navigation` than it is possible without SharePoint Designer or any Custom code than you can follow steps in below mentioned link.

[No-Code Global Navigation Flyouts in SharePoint 2013](https://newsignature.com/articles/no-code-global-navigation-flyout-dropdown-sharepoint-2013-online)